# Surjectivity and injectivity for all linear transformations $T : ℝ^n → ℝ^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that in order for a linear transformation $T : ℝ^n → ℝ^m$ to be surjective, $m$ must be less than or equal to $n$ and for it to be injective, $n$ must be less than or equal to $m$, but is the converse of both statements also true (i.e. does $m<=n$ imply surjectivity and $n<=m$ imply injectivity for all linear transformations $T$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example take $n=m=2$ and the linear map given by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
It is not surjective onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ (nothing in the image has nonzero second component), nor injective (both $(1,0)^\top$ and $(1,1)^\top$ map to $(1,0)^\top$).

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, for example, let $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ be given by $Tx=Ax$ where

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\2 & 4\end{bmatrix}.$$

The kernel of this map is $\{(-2x,x):x\in\Bbb R\}$. The range is $\{(x,2x):x\in\Bbb R\}$  Therefore the map is neither injective nor surjective.